# different image size alignment in div

Tags: css, alignment

i have a different size image in a my box header.

```
 <div class='divboxheader'>
<img class='imgstyle' src="http://www.bnbsync.com/themes/bnbsync/assets/images/logo-dark.png" />
<span class='textleft textcustom'><b>text of title1</b></span>
<span class='textright'>text</span>
```

[this is a screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzLxM.jpg)

How can I align the text of different row?

complete example:
https://jsfiddle.net/tcggk8ya/1

Comment: Your question is very unclear, what is the exact problem, what do you expect, what do you get?

Comment: hello, you are right. i'm attach screenshot and complete example :(

Comment: Ok, so the widths of the images are different causing the texts to have a different position...

Comment: perfect. Yes :)

Comment: Added an answer with example on how to fix this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are relying on inconsistent content (the image width) to generate the spacing of you text. There are multiple solutions to this problem but I recommend wrapping the img inside a fixed with container.

I created a quick 'n dirty example that shows how this can be done using semantic set of tags.

```css
.boxlist {
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.boxlist__item {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

.boxlist__item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.boxlist__figure {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 .boxlist__figure-img {
   width: auto;
   height: 25px;
   margin-right: 0;
}

.boxlist__figure-label {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.boxlist__content {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Arial";
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.boxlist__actions {
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.boxlist__action {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="boxlist">
  <li class="boxlist__item">
    <figure class="boxlist__figure">
      <img class='boxlist__figure-img' src="http://www.bnbsync.com/themes/bnbsync/assets/images/logo-dark.png" />
      <span class="boxlist__figure-label">My label</span>
    </figure>
    
    <strong class="boxlist__content">Some user</strong>
    
    <ul class="boxlist__actions">
      <li class="boxlist__action">action 1</li>
      <li class="boxlist__action">action 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li class="boxlist__item">
    <figure class="boxlist__figure">
      <img class='boxlist__figure-img' src="http://www.bnbsync.com/themes/bnbsync/assets/images/logo-dark.png" />
      <span class="boxlist__figure-label">My label</span>
    </figure>
    
    <strong class="boxlist__content">Some user</strong>
    
    <ul class="boxlist__actions">
      <li class="boxlist__action">action 1</li>
      <li class="boxlist__action">action 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li class="boxlist__item">
    <figure class="boxlist__figure">
      <img class='boxlist__figure-img' src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-iRkoc0wxL4w/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAk/PTyC2SH4ZqE/photo.jpg?sz=110" />
      <span class="boxlist__figure-label">My label</span>
    </figure>
    
    <strong class="boxlist__content">Some user</strong>
    
    <ul class="boxlist__actions">
      <li class="boxlist__action">action 1</li>
      <li class="boxlist__action">action 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use table-layout or flex-layout

I made an example with table layout:

https://jsfiddle.net/L2gc6s16/

by doing the following:

1: divbox has to be display:table

2: wrap your img into a  an give the span's display:table-cell

3: specify a width for your table-cell that contains image:

```
.divboxheader span:first-child {
  width:50px;
}
```

4: set the width of img to 100%

5: remove floats